# xargs split at newlines not spaces

Tags: shell, unix, xargs

here is my problem in short

```
$ echo 'for i in $@; do echo arg: $i; done; echo DONE' > /tmp/test.sh
$ echo "ac\nbc\ncc\n" | xargs bash /tmp/test.sh 
arg: ac
arg: bc
arg: cc
DONE
```

Which is what i expect, but

```
$ echo "ac s\nbc s\ncc s\n" | xargs -d \n bash /tmp/test.sh
arg: ac
arg: s
arg: bc
arg: s
arg: cc
arg: s
DONE
```

Shouldn't the output be?

```
arg: ac s
arg: bc s
arg: cc s
DONE
```

How do I get the 2nd output with xargs?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try:

```
printf %b 'ac s\nbc s\ncc s\n' | xargs -d '\n' bash /tmp/test.sh
```

**You neglected to quote the `\n`** passed to `-d`, which means that just `n` rather than `\n` was passed to `xargs` as the delimiter - the shell "ate" the `\` (when the shell parses an unquoted string,  `\` functions as an escape character; if an ordinary character follows the `\` - `n` in this case - only that ordinary character is used).

Also heed @glenn jackman's advice to double-quote the `$@` inside the script (or omit the `in "$@"` part altogether).

Also: **`xargs -d` is a GNU extension**, which, for instance, won't work on FreeBSD/macOS. To make it work there, see @glenn jackman's `xargs -0`-based solution.

---

Note that I'm using `printf` rather than `echo` to ensure that the `\n` instances in the string are interpreted as newlines in *all* Bourne-like shells:
In `bash` and `ksh`<sup>[1]</sup>, `echo` defaults to NOT interpreting `\`-based escape sequences (you have to use `-e` to achieve that) - unlike in `zsh` and strictly POSIX-compliant shells such as `dash`.
Therefore, `printf` is the more portable choice.

<sup>[1] According to the manual, `ksh`'s `echo` *builtin* exhibits the same behavior as the host platform's external `echo` *utility*; while this may vary across platforms, the Linux and BSD/macOS implementations do *not* interpret `\` escape sequences by default.</sup>

Comment: note- new line is not always `\n` . for windows it is `\r\n`

Comment: @ParamvirSinghKarwal: Yes, but note that the question is tagged [tag:unix].

Comment: just in case someone is fiddling with windows style files in unix environment.

Answer (score 29):

## On Mac OSX

For simple cases that have a known number of args, tell xargs how many args to send to each command. For example

```
$ printf "1\n2\n3" | xargs -n1 echo "#"
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

When your input args are complex, and newline terminated, a better method is:

```
$ printf "1\n2 3\n4 5 6" | xargs -L1 echo  "#"
# 1
# 2 3
# 4 5 6
```

There is a problem here, can you see it? What if our input line contains a single quote:

```
$ printf "1\n2 3\n4 '5 6" | xargs -L1 echo  "#"
# 1
# 2 3
xargs: unterminated quote
```

Single quotes and other quoting characters have special meaning to `xargs` [unless you use the `-0` flag](http://earlh.com/blog/2012/06/24/howto-make-find-xargs-grep-robust-to-spaces-in-filenames-on-a-mac/). But `-0` and `-L1` are not compatible, so that leaves us with:

```
$ printf "1\n2 3\n4 '5 6" | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -I {} echo "#" {}
# 1
# 2 3
# 4 '5 6
```

If you `brew install findutils` we can do a little better:

```
$ printf "1\n2 3\n4 '5 6" | gxargs -d\\n -i echo "#" {}
# 1
# 2 3
# 4 '5 6
```

But wait, maybe using `xargs` is just a bad tool for this one. What if we use the shell builtins instead:

```
$ printf "1\n2 3\n4 '5 6\n" | while read -r; do echo "# $REPLY"; done
# 1
# 2 3
# 4 '5 6
```

For some more thoughts about `xargs` vs `while` checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574134/when-should-xargs-be-preferred-over-while-read-loops).

Comment: "`xargs -0 -I{} echo "#" {}`" Nitpick: There should be a space after `-I`.  Only the non-portable `-i` option has no space after it. <https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html>

Comment: `echo` is not suitable for testing if the arguments are correctly split. Try `... | xargs -d'\n' printf "[%s]\n"` instead and you can definitely see how the input is split – and try without the `-d` flag, too. Note that the default MacOS `xargs` typically fails to support `-d` flag.

Comment: When I run your first example, I got `# 1n2n3`

Comment: @nos yes, echo is shell dependent. I will update to use printf.

Comment: quotes are fine, they just need to be escaped `printf '%s\n' "1" "2 3" "4 \'5 6" | xargs -L1`

Answer (score 8):

Your shell script needs to use `"$@"` not `$@`

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters

---

I see in the xargs manual on my machine:

> xargs reads items from  the  standard  input,
>          delimited  by  **blanks  [...] or newlines**

(emphasis mine)

Thus:

```
$ echo $'ac s\nbc s\ncc s\n' | xargs bash /tmp/test.sh  
arg: ac
arg: s
arg: bc
arg: s
arg: cc
arg: s
DONE

$ printf "%s\0" "ac s" "bc s" "cc s" | xargs -0 bash /tmp/test.sh
arg: ac s
arg: bc s
arg: cc s
DONE
```

With the former, you get the equivalent of

```
bash /tmp/test.sh ac s bc s cc s
```

versus using null-separator

```
bash /tmp/test.sh "ac s" "bc s" "cc s"
```

You need to be clear about what the delimiter is with xargs when the data contains whitespace.

```
$ printf "%s\n" "ac s" "bc s" "cc s" | xargs -d $'\n' bash /tmp/test.sh
arg: ac s
arg: bc s
arg: cc s
DONE

$ echo $'ac s\nbc s\ncc s\n' | xargs -d $'\n' bash /tmp/test.sh  
arg: ac s
arg: bc s
arg: cc s
arg:  
DONE
```

Note the extra arg in the last case, `echo` already adds a newline, so you don't need an extra one unless you use `echo -n`

Comment: Good advice, though the real problem lies with not quoting the `\n` passed to `-d`.

Comment: You're absolutely right: _both_ issues need to be addressed to fix the problem (and they each in isolation or combination produce the symptom). Your `printf`-`\0`-`xargs -0` solution is a nice alternative, because it is more portable (will work on OSX too, for instance, where `xargs -d` is not available).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `test.sh` is something like

```
echo arg: "$@"
```

As already pointed out, you need to escape `-d '\n'` and it should be noted that this is a GNU extension. It basically is a shortcut to the posix compatible `tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0`

But `xargs` is more versatile and subtle in many cases. It can be used to massage parameters very precisely and can be well illustrated using `sh` `printf`. `cat -A` is used to clearly show the difference.

In a nutshell, `xargs` splits on whitespace and it treats newlines specially.

To only split on newlines, use `-d '\n'` or `tr '\n' '\0'` or use something like `sed` to escape spaces and tabs.

---

Process invoked once, with three arguments.

```
printf '%s\n' "ac s" "bc s" "cc s" |
  xargs -d '\n' sh -c 'printf "%s\t" arg: "$@"'';printf "\n"' xargs-example |
  cat -A
```

```
arg:^Iac s^Ibc s^Icc s^I$
```

---

Process invoked once, with 6 arguments.

```
printf '%s\n' "ac s" "bc s" "cc s" |
   xargs sh -c 'printf "%s\t" arg: "$@"'';printf "\n"' xargs-example |
   cat -A
```

```
arg:^Iac^Is^Ibc^Is^Icc^Is^I$
```

---

Process invoked twice, with 4 and 2 arguments respectively

```
printf '%s\n' "ac s" "bc s" "cc s" |
    xargs -L2 sh -c 'printf "%s\t" arg: "$@"'';printf "\n"' xargs-example |
    cat -A
```

```
arg:^Iac^Is^Ibc^Is^I$
arg:^Icc^Is^I$
```

---

Process invoked twice, with 2 and 1 arguments respectively.

```
printf '%s\n' "ac s" "bc s" "cc s" |
     xargs -d '\n' -L2 sh -c 'printf "%s\t" arg: "$@"'';printf "\n"' xargs-example |
     cat -A
```

```
arg:^Iac s^Ibc s^I$
arg:^Icc s^I$
```

---

This may seem a bit complicated but it allows you to use tabs and newlines to control `xargs` where tabs become argument separators and newlines control which arguments each process is invoked with, ie.

Process invoked twice, with 3 and 1 argument respectively

```
printf '%s\n' ac$'\t's "bc s" "cc s" |
   sed '
# escape spaces
s@ @\\ @g
   ' |
   xargs -L2 sh -c 'printf "%s\t" arg: "$@"'';printf "\n"' xargs-example |
   cat -A
```

```
arg:^Iac^Is^Ibc s^I$
arg:^Icc s^I$
```